# Updating Firebase Analytics user properties with every event

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my project, we are using custom user properties to allow our marketing team to analyze the structure of our user base. One of our properties indicates if a user has an active premium membership. As a premium is given for a specific period, it gets removed automatically after the time has elapsed.

We want all of our users to have that property (by default set to false), and being as up to date as possible. As properties are being attached to the next sent event - we came up with the idea of calling set_property with local states every time a new event is sent. That way we won't constraint ourselves to only sending it on login or other specific actions, and re-use already implemented components that always hold up to date information about these states.

So here is a question; How would that affect data usage and firebase overall? Does firebase have some internal mechanism that detects if a new property state is the same as the previous one and does not attach it if it did not change? As far as I understand it attaches user properties to all events anyway, so just calling set_property on every event to enforce data synchronization would have any impact at all?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS We are talking about both Android and iOS apps here, hope underlying implementation for both of them is the same.